# Loopback Context is found null in model beforeCreate when using Mocha

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have a model that access context object (to get currentUser) in beforeCreate.

```
myModel.beforeCreate = function(next, md) {

    var Category = md.app.models.Category;

    var ctx = loopback.getCurrentContext();
    var currentUser = ctx && ctx.get('currentUser');
   ...
  });
```

It works when I normally access it from explorer but when I try to access it using mocha in unit test

I get error because currentUser is not set.

So, when I try to set currentUser, I don't get context object in tests.

```
var ctx = loopback.getCurrentContext();
        if (ctx) console.log("CTX exists");
```

here ctx is null.

Please suggest where I have gone wrong.

Cheers
Raj

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use the [loopback-testing](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-testing/) module you'll have success more easily here.  Specifically the `givenLoggedInUser` function creates a user for your test and logs that user in, creating a saved token as well.

```
var lt = require('loopback-testing');
var credentials = { email: 'user@example.com', password: 'pwd' }
lt.givenLoggedInUser(credentials, 'user');
it('should have a logged in user', function (done) {
  if (loopback.getCurrentContext()) {
    console.log("CTX exists", this.user);
  }
});
```

This should also create the current context you need.  Take a look at the rest middleware tests for more help here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/test/rest.middleware.test.js#L128